Column headers with equal height based on dynamic content
enter image description here
I need a layout where there are 3 columns with each containing a header section and content section. The headers of all 3 column has to be equal based on dynamic content length. The content section height can be based on its content.
Note: on smaller screen / if one column wraps only the first 2 column header should have the equal height. Since last header is below it can have content height to avoid white space.
I have tried with flex, grid and I dont want to use JS as there is jerk on applying the css.
Below is the css I have tried with
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .column {
        flex: 1 0 30.33%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .header {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: stretch;
        min-height: 100px; /* Adjust this value based on your needs */
        border:1px solid red;
    }

    .details {
        text-align: center;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        border:1px solid red;

    }

    .header > p {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
</style>


I don't think you can have both, wrapping independent columns and column headers reacting to each other's content, without using explicit header heights or JS
